# Django admin filtering based on user profile

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have the following models in django:

```
class Manager(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 

class Admin(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In Djanog admin I would like to filter based on the company field of Manager OR Admin based on which is currently logged in.

I have the followin code for this:

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(EmployeeAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        return qs
    if hasattr(request.user, 'manager'):
        return qs.filter(company=request.user.manager.company)
    elif hasattr(request.user, 'admin'):
        return qs.filter(company=request.user.admin.company)
```

It works nice, but I don't really like the way I have to allways check with hasattr() function which one is logged in. Also this is an error prone way, if I add another role for eg: Employer besides Manager and Ddmin and I forget to handle Employer...

Could you recommend a more neat solution for this?
Thank you!

Comment: Encapsulate the logic in a function, such that you use the function, and not each time implement this in another view.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem isnt it already encapsulated inside a function?